# Composer always install the latest version, if the package version separated by logical OR

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Composer don't install the package with versions separated by logical OR.

First image. As expected, I got all `5.x` versions.

```
    "require": {
        "illuminate/http": "^5"
    },
```

[image: "illuminate/http": "^5"]

Second image:

```
    "require": {
        "illuminate/http": "^5||^6"
    },
```

[image: "illuminate/http": "^5||^6"]

I expect to get all `5.x` versions and all `6.x` versions, but always get the **one** latest version.

How to fix this?

Comment: Which command are you calling? Are there any other requirements?

Comment: "locked at v7.12.0" implies the lock file already has 7.12.0 specified for the package... deleting the lock file and running composer update should allow v5 or v6 to be installed, but I think it would use v6.max without any other requirements specified. I think it's lame that composer chokes on pre-existing lock file specs instead of just going by the json file, but hey I didn't write composer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install multiple versions of the same package. Composer just doesn't support that, and it's unlikely that will change given it's mostly oriented towards php. You could try installing via bower, but I don't think it supports two versions at once either..

**For more details** https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

Comment: I don't want to install multiple versions, I just want to my library support ANY of versions from the list. 5.x or 6.x, any of COMPATIBLE with other project dependencies.

Comment: My library support both 5.x and 6.x versions of the dependency. I want to if the project contains library that supports only 5.x of the dependency it supports my library. And if the project contains library that supports only 6.x of the dependency it also supports my library. I want to composer decides itself which version of the dependency to install based on compatibility with other dependencies. But now it just always try to install the latest version.

Comment: You can try this command to validate your *composer.json* `php composer.phar validate`

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I understood.
This is the fault of the `composer.lock`. Usually, **you should not commit `composer.lock` to vcs if you are making a library**.

Because then the version of the dependency of your library will be locked at the **one** specific version.

But usually library must be compatible with as many versions of the dependency as possible.

Also, you can't install one of compatible versions of the dependency if you already have installed one (even you delete `composer.lock`).

`composer.lock` force point version to the specific value, can't install one of  compatible with other dependencies:
[image: locked]

You already have some installed version, can't install another one. Even if your `composer.json` allows to install one of compatible versions.
[image: installed]

So, I just delete `/vendor` and `composer.lock` and composer select one of the compatible versions itself.

Comment: Please share more details. Which library are you talking about? And how should that library be installed if `composer.json`  is missing? That's how **all** libraries work, and I've installed Symfony on multiple projects without any problem

Comment: Nico, oh, of course I meant `composer.lock`. Thank your for ping.

Comment: And what makes you think that the `composer.lock` commited to a library repository is taken into account when that library is installed?

Comment: Ok, for example. Laravel framework replaces some packages whose called `illuminate/xxx` with it's own realizations. I create the CI config that install various laravel versions instead of `illuminate` packages to check the compatibility of my library with those laravel versions. And it's impossible to install laravel, if the library has `composer.lock` file. Because laravel replaces `illuminate` packages to it's own version, but the `illuminate` packages versions force set to a different version from laravel.

Comment: See https://travis-ci.com/github/CaliforniaMountainSnake/json-response/builds/167892469 . Only the latest version of laravel passed check, because it's version is equals to the latest version of the dependency that is force set in `composer.lock`